# Event Listener running only once with Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I created a `Promise` here to connect to the `storage` and I also need to listen for changes.

With window.onstorage inside the promise it only listens once, even though it dispatches two events.

I can only listen to the two events dispatched if I put it directly in `useEffect` and without `Promise`.

Is it possible to listen to an event inside a Promise?
If so how should I do it and what is wrong?

**CODE**

```
    const connect = useCallback(
        () =>
            new Promise<IConnectFunction>((resolve, reject) => {
                Promise.all([infuraStorageData, metamaskStorageData])
                    .then(response => {
                        window.onstorage = e => {
                            resolve({
                                infuraData: response[0],
                                metamaskData: response[1],
                            });
                        };
                    })
                    .catch((error: DOMException) => reject(error));
            }),
        [infuraStorageData, metamaskStorageData]
    );

useEffect(() => {
        useStorageDBHook
            .connect()
            .then(e => {
                console.log(e);
                // window.onstorage = e => {
                //  console.log(e);
                // };
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }, [useStorageDBHook]);
```

Comment: But that's a feature of `Promise`, it can only resolve once. Further call to `resolve(value)` has no effect, you can't change that. So let's not waste our time on `Promise` which's an obvious dead end. Allow me to ask: what exactly do you want to achieve, in terms of expected result?

Comment: I'm creating a hook to control the "database" which is localstorage and session storage. I created this connect function, to be able to start the "database", get the updated data if it is the first entry and or if the listener returns new data.

Comment: Then using `Promise` (a thenable) as the interface is wrong move. You are describing some kind of stream (an observable, or subscribable) interface, which will continuously feed you new data whenever available (in your case, whenever `onstorage` event fires).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Promise` by design can only resolve once. Further call to resolve(value) has no effect.

If you want to receive (get notified) multiple events, you need some kind of stream interface (aka an observable, or subscribable), which will continuously feed you new data whenever available (in your case, whenever onstorage event fires).

A hand-rolled subscribable interface can be implemented like this:

```js
class Subscribable {
  constructor(source) {
    this.subscribers = [];
    source(this.notify.bind(this));
  }

  subscribe(sink) {
    this.subscribers = this.subscribers.concat(push);
    const unsubscribe = () => {
      this.subscribers = this.subscribers.filter((_sink) => _sink !== sink);
    };
    return unsubscribe;
  }

  notify(newValue, error) {
    this.subscribers.forEach((sink) => sink(newValue, error));
  }
}
```

The usage is very close to `Promise`, you replace `(resolve, reject)` with a single `notify` callback, you cannot chain it with a `.catch` though, which is admittedly a bit drawback.

```js
const connect = useCallback(
  () =>
    new Subscribable((notify) => {
      // I took the liberty to change your code a bit
      // cus it looks confusing, I guess your real intention is like:
      window.onstorage = (e) => { notify(e) };
      Promise.all([infuraStorageData, metamaskStorageData])
        .then((response) => {
          notify({
            infuraData: response[0],
            metamaskData: response[1],
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => notify(null, error));
    }),
  [infuraStorageData, metamaskStorageData]
);

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = connect().subscribe((newValue, error) => {
    if (error) {
      // handle error
    } else {
      console.log(newValue);
    }
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, [connect]);
```